# Python Bar Chart X axis re-naming matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

my question is simply how would I change the X-axis[OUTCOME OF CODE FOR BAR CHART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9ls6.png)

**from the numbers (Ex. 17, 1, 2, 4) to the PET names (Ex. Horse, Dog, etc). Code Below**

I'm new to stack overflow but here is an image of the code. I'll eventually figure out how to use it.

[Here is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGJer.png)

**CSV DOWN BELOW**

```
Height,Ice Cream,Pet,#of letters,Favorite TA,Minutes to Hometown
67,Chocolate,Dog,16,Ryan,55
63,Cookie Dough,None,15,Mimi,180
75,Vanilla,Dog,20,Peter,150
66,Moose Tracks,Dog,16,Erik,300
72,Vanilla,Dog,17,Ryan,60
66,Moose Tracks,Dog,14,Emily,85
72,Chocolate,None,21,Josh,70
72,Mint Chip,Cat,9,Abe,70
71,Vanilla,Dog,20,Brian,90
75,Vanilla,Dog,5,None,105
68,Strawberry,Horse,19,Emily,120
59,Chocolate,Dog,13,Cezanne,45
73,Vanilla,Dog,14,Monica,155
64,Chocolate,None,16,Sarah,120
67,Mint Chip,Dog,21,Kelly,180
67,Mint Chip,Dog,20,Ryan,90
68,Cookies & Cream,Dog,13,Toner,180
65,Chocolate,Dog,20,None,60
75,Chocolate,Dog,9,Chris,120
67,Cookie Dough,None,10,Katie,75
67,Vanilla,Dog,24,Carlos,120
75,Mint Chip,Dog,17,Tim,180
64,Vanilla,Dog,15,Xavier,135
74,Cookies & Cream,Horse,18,Jeff,180
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h2 = pd.read_csv("hw_2_data.csv")

## create grouped dataframe
h2Grouped = h2.groupby('Pet').count()
##h2Grouped

##recreate serverity variable
h2Grouped['Pet'] = h2Grouped.index
## rename the variables
h2Grouped.columns = ['Count', 'Pet', 'Ice Cream', '#of letters', 'Favorite TA', 'Minutes to Hometown']

#matplot
%matplotlib inline

##bar
bar1 = h2Grouped.plot.bar(x = 'Pet', y = 'Count', title = 'Pet Bar Chart')
bar1.set_xlabel('Pet')

##get rid of text output
t = bar1.set_ylabel('Count')
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Pet').count()['Height'].plot(kind='bar', rot=0)` is all you need. The x-axis names are based on the index, not the column names.

Comment: `df.Pet.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)` is even better.

Comment: Thank you guys very much it works perfectly now.